# Calculus: Derive $\frac{-x+5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on the following problem:

$$f(x)=\frac{-x+5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$

I tried working through the problem using quotient rule and got here:

[image]

The solution is:

$$f'(x)=\frac{-5x-1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$$

Where did I go wrong?  A step by step through would be appreciated.

Comment: In the second term of your first equation, you left out the factor $2x$.

Comment: Remark: it's differentiate, not derive.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you include this bit of the set-up, if you are going to dodge using the quotient rule.

$f(x) = (-x+5)(x^2 + 1)^{-\frac 12}$

on to differentiation.

$f'(x) = -(x^2 + 1)^{-\frac 12} + (-x+5)(-\frac 12)(x^2 + 1)^{-\frac32}(2x)$

Looks like you missed the $2x$ factor that arises from the application of the chain rule.

That is 
$u = x^2 + 1, v = u^{-\frac 12}\\
\frac {dv}{dx} = \frac {dv}{du}\frac {du}{dx}\\
\frac {dv}{du} = -\frac 12 u^{-\frac 32}\\
\frac{du}{dx} = 2x\\
\frac {dv}{dx} = -\frac 12 u^{-\frac 32}(2x)$

Simplifying, factor out the smallest (most negative) power of the common factor $(x^2 + 1)$

And $(-\frac 12)(2x) = -x$

$f'(x) = (x^2 + 1)^{-\frac32} [ -(x^2 + 1) + (-x+5)(-x)]\\
 = (x^2 + 1)^{-\frac32} [ -x^2 - 1 +x^2 - 5x]\\
 = (x^2 + 1)^{-\frac32} [ -5x- 1]\\
-\frac {5x + 1}{(x^2 + 1)^\frac 32}$

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate $x^2$ as you're differentiating  w.r.t $x$.

So, $$f'(x) = \frac d{dx}\left(\frac{-x+5}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\left(-\frac12\right) \frac{(-x+5)2x}{(x^2+1)^\frac32} = \frac{-x^2-1-(-x+5)x}{(x^2+1)^\frac32}=\frac{-5x-1}{(x^2+1)^\frac32}$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Recall the quotient rule: $(f/g)'=\dfrac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$.

So, we have $f(x)=-x+5$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

So we get $\dfrac{(-1)\sqrt{x^2+1}-(-x+5)(1/2)(2x)(x^2+1)^{-1/2}}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{-x^2-1+x^2-5x}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}=\dfrac{-5x-1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

*A small trick I "discovered" almost $65$ years ago which makes life much easier when facing products, quotients, powers ... :* **logarithmic differentition**
$$f(x)=\frac{-x+5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \implies\log(f(x))=\log(-x+5)-\frac 12 \log(x^2+1)$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{-1}{-x+5}-\frac 12 \frac {2x} {x^2+1}=\frac {-5x-1}{(-x+5)(x^2+1)}$$
$$f'(x)=f(x) \times\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= \frac{-x+5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \times \frac {-5x-1}{(-x+5)(x^2+1)}=-\frac{5 x+1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$